# How to select element by specific child/descendant element

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

```html
<a class="author " name="baut001" href="#!">
   <span class="content">
      <span class=" given-name">first name</span>
      <span class=" surname">Last name</span>
      <svg focusable="false" viewBox="128" width="19.125" height="24" class="icon ">
         <path d="m22.6 77"></path>
      </svg>
   </span>
</a>
<a class="author" name="baut002" href="#!">
<span class="content">
<span class="text given-name">first name</span>
<span class="text surname">Last name</span>
<span class="author-ref" id="baff002"><sup>a</sup></span>
</span>
</a>
<a class="author" name="baut003" href="#!">
   <span class="content">
      <span class=" given-name">first name</span>
      <span class=" surname">Last name</span>
      <svg focusable="false" viewBox="128" width="19.125" height="24" class="icon ">
         <path d="m22.6 77"></path>
      </svg>
   </span>
</a>
```

There are three `<a>` tags two among them contains `<svg>` tags, I want to click those elements.

Comment: 1. Find out all the `a` tags. 
2. Now iterate all the `a` tags and check if it have `svg` is available or not?
3. If available then click the `a` else skip. 
this is a way to solve the problem.

Comment: "3. If available then click the a else skip," this is what i want, how to check whether it is having "svg" tag or not.

Comment: @scooprealm _...click those elements..._ which element do you want to click exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to locate node that contains another node you might need to use XPath in below format

1. By child node:

   ```
   //parent_node[child_node]
   ```

   or

   ```
   //parent_node[child::child_node]
   ```
2. By descendant node:

   ```
   //anscestor_node[.//descendant_node]
   ```

   or

   ```
   //anscestor_node[descendant::descendant_node]
   ```

In your case to select `a` node that contains `svg` descendant node, you can try;

```
links_with_svg = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[.//*[local-name()="svg"]]')
```

or

```
links_with_svg = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[descendant::*[local-name()="svg"]]')
```

Comment: Some day I'll jeopardize your reputation by asking a very difficult question concerning xpath. However, your solution always brings up something new to learn @sir Andersson.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the `<svg>` tag in the locator.

You can use `css_selector`

```
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.author svg')
```

Or `xpath`

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[@class="author"]//*[local-name()="svg"]')
```

Comment: Actually the XPath is incorrect! `svg` tags are not from standard HTML namespace, so you cannot select it with `//svg`, you need `//*[local-name()="svg"]` instead. Also your selectors intend to locate *`svg` that is descendant of link*, but not *link that contains `svg`*